# fullcalendar: Onclick event of day view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've looked through the fullcalendar documentation, but I'm unsure where I can call the onclick event of clicking the "Day" view button of the calendar.

I have a button I've added to the header, and I only want this button viewable while on Week view.  So when the user changes to day view, I'd like to hide it.

I would also like the button's text to change depending on the current week being viewed, but I'm unsure how to call the onclick for the change week arrows.

Anyone have any idea how to call these?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You would have to create external buttons to simulate switch between views ( you can search for that here in SO ) and then with jquery bind the onclick event to the external div's/buttons ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce the result I needed through the ViewDisplay() function (which apparently is now the ViewRender() function).  This was able to detect change in views I needed to accomplish my goal.

Thanks @Henrique C. for your suggestion.